authMiddleware doesn't exist after installing clerk
I tried installing authMiddleware for a tutorial using clerk but got an error saying that it doesn't exist.
I was installing clerk for this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a02JAryRPVU, and I ran npm install @clerk/nextjs.
Then I put this code to enable authentication using authMiddleware
import { authMiddleware } from "@clerk/nextjs";

export default authMiddleware({});

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!.+.[w]+$|_next).*)", "/", "/(api|trpc)(.*)"],
};

but I got an error, saying Module '"@clerk/nextjs"' has no exported member 'authMiddleware'.
When running the code through localhost, I got this error: TypeError: (0 , clerk_nextjs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_.authMiddleware) is not a function
I don't know how to fix this issue, any help would be appreciated.

I think the problem is the latest version of clerk, you may use the previous stable version of clerk (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@clerk/nextjs/v/4.30.0), this resolution fixed my problem.
npm i @clerk/nextjs@4.30.0


The clerk team has deprecated authMiddleware. They suggest you use clerkMiddleware() instead.
https://clerk.com/docs/references/nextjs/auth-middleware
So, if you use clerkMiddleware() your middleware.ts will now look like this.
import { clerkMiddleware } from '@clerk/nextjs/server';
 
export default clerkMiddleware()
 
export const config = {
  matcher: [
    '/((?!.*\\..*|_next).*)', // Don't run middleware on static files
    '/', // Run middleware on index page
    '/(api|trpc)(.*)'], // Run middleware on API routes
};


Thanks for the tip! The website still uses authMiddleware though.

I think they have not yet updated their dashboard docs but they have changed their quickstart docs. https://clerk.com/docs/quickstarts/nextjs

Can you Just add the /server at the end of import location, it be like:
import { authMiddleware } from '@clerk/nextjs/server';

i recomend to use the clerkMiddleware because the type authMiddleware go be discontinued.

and you can use the least version of clerk package.

On April 22 2024, the beta version should be installed to use clerkMiddleware()
npm install @clerk/nextjs@beta


Add the paths you are having issues into the middleware and it will work
for example in the matcher you have to add you path like   "/companion/[companionId]"

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

For anyone who needs to use clerkmiddleware instead of authmiddleware,
I had the infinite redirect loop (ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECT). This is because clerkmiddleware's default code doesn't protect any route. If you want to protect routes (Means users can't see some routes without logging in) using clerkmiddleware, here is the code for it and it worked for me. This code protects all routes except the sign-in and sign-up routes. If you want only some of the routes to be protected, you can adjust the part below:
const isPublicRoute = createRouteMatcher(['/sign-in(.*)', '/sign-up(.*)']); 

Here is the middleware.ts
import { clerkMiddleware, createRouteMatcher } from '@clerk/nextjs/server'

const isPublicRoute = createRouteMatcher(['/sign-in(.*)', '/sign-up(.*)']);

export default clerkMiddleware((auth, request) => {
  if(!isPublicRoute(request)) {
    auth().protect();
  }
});

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/((?!.*\\..*|_next).*)', '/', '/(api|trpc)(.*)'],
};

Also, here is the documentation link : https://clerk.com/docs/references/nextjs/clerk-middleware

I was struggling with this as well because I started off with the deprecated version of Clerk. However, I found that resolving the syntax errors using the linters available and then quickly updating clerk at the terminal resolved my issue. Just try and run npm i @clerk/nextjs@latest  at the terminal. This should solve the challenge. Ensure you resolve or syntax issues. It might also be helpful to use this documentation:
https://clerk.com/docs/quickstarts/nextjs

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
